# Batch file to edit users path

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch

I have a batch file that I got from another post in this forum which edits the user's path but it bombs if the path contains any Program Files (x86) entries that are common on windows 7 machines. Any idea's how to fix the script so it works with these entries?

```
@echo OFF

set KEY_NAME="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"
set VALUE_NAME=Path

FOR /F "usebackq skip=4 tokens=1-3" %%A IN (`REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% /v %VALUE_NAME% 2^>nul`) DO (
  set ValueName=%%A
  set ValueValue=%%C
)

if defined ValueName (

  set newPath=%ValueValue%;C:\bin

  reg.exe ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d %newPath% /f

  set path=%path%;C:\bin

) else (
    @echo %KEY_NAME%\%VALUE_NAME% not found.
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The script fails because the `)` in `Program Files (x86)` is prematurly closing the code block in you IF statment.

Here is a quick and dirty fix that should get you past that problem, though the code is still not very robust.

```
@echo OFF
set KEY_NAME="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"
set VALUE_NAME=Path
FOR /F "usebackq skip=4 tokens=1-3" %%A IN (`REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% /v %VALUE_NAME% 2^>nul`) DO (
  set ValueName=%%A
  set ValueValue=%%C
)
if not defined ValueName (
  @echo %KEY_NAME%\%VALUE_NAME% not found.
  exit /b
)
set newPath=%ValueValue%;C:\bin
reg.exe ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d %newPath% /f
set path=%path%;C:\bin
```